# Is there a solution to 'Windows does not recognise this device' trying to connect a Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb-drivers

I have tried loads of ways to connect my phone to my PC (it used to work!).
The PC will not even recognise the phone as a device anymore. I have also tried reinstalling the drivers via [Samsung Kies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies). What is the solution?

Comment: Have you installed other USB drivers that might be conflicting with it?  I had the same problem and eventually found it was caused by an old version of Microsoft ActiveSync.  Once I removed ActiveSync, I was able to connect my Galaxy S again.

Comment: Try some other USB cables and ports as well.

Comment: Just wanted to echo what @Matthew said.  I've had experiences with bad USB cables.  Also, Samsung Galaxy S phones have a somewhat recessed micro-USB connection, so you have to make sure that whatever cable you use really gets down in there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the SD card and the SIM card. Restart the phone and only plug it in when its restarted completely. Make sure the phone is set to USB Kies. Check the cables too!

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall the Galaxy S drivers from the Device Manager in Windows while it is plugged in, and then reconnect the phone to the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Ubuntu and Windows. Just today after installing Dropbox ( which is a good workaround BTW) after the following steps, my phone was recognized as if it were a flash drive:

power off.
connect USB to PC.
charge for a while ( irrelevant I assume)
power on while connected.

I don't know whether Dropbox changed some setting or permission, whether something else I played with did, or the power-off-on sequence fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Try to disable USB debugging. When you connect you will then have a button labelled "Connect USB" on the phone. Press it and it will install itself. It worked for me.